# Extending an Object in Perl

Tags: perl, object

I've got a base object called RuleObject and an object that inherits from that called RuleObjectString. I have a new method in RuleObjectString that I want to call in my code that uses that object. But I get the error. **'Can't locate object method "compare" via package "RuleObject" at ./testobject.pl line 10.'** But I'm not creating a RuleObject. I'm creating a RuleObjectString. What am I doing wrong here?

testobject.pl

```
  1 #! /usr/bin/perl
  2
  3 use strict;
  4
  5 use RuleObjectString;
  6
  7 my $s = RuleObjectString->new();
  8 $s->value('stuff goes here');
  9
 10 if ($s->compare('stuff')){
 11         print "MATCH!\n";
 12 }else{
 13         print "no match :(\n";
 14 }
```

RuleObject.pm

```
package RuleObject;

our @ISA = qw/Exporter/;
our @EXPORT = qw/new/;

use strict;

sub new{
        my $class = shift;

        my $self;
        $self->{value} = undef;

        bless $self;
        return $self;
}

sub value{
        my $self = shift;
        my $value = shift;
        if ($value){
                $self->{value} = $value;
        }else{
                return $self->{value};
        }
}
```

RuleObjectString.pm

```
package RuleObjectString;

our @ISA = qw/RuleObject/;
our @EXPORT = qw/compare/;

use strict;

sub compare{
        my $self = shift;
        my $compareto = shift;

        return $self->value() =~ /$compareto/;
}
```

Comment: You should not `@EXPORT` your class and instance methods, and your modules generally should not inherit `Exporter` unless they have bona fide procedural functions to export.

Comment: And for cases where you need to export *functions*, `Sub::Exporter` is much nicer interface wise than `Exporter` . But you should probably avoid exporting functions from packages that are also class definitions. '

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think jmcneirney is on the right track. In your `RuleObject` constructor, you say

```
bless $self;
```

which is the same as

```
bless $self, __PACKAGE__;
```

or

```
bless $self, 'RuleObject'
```

but what you want is for the object to blessed as a `RuleObjectString`. So what you want to do is say

```
bless $self, $class
```

Now

```
RuleObject->new()
RuleObjectString->new()
```

will both call the same constructor, but the object returned by the first call will be blessed as a `RuleObject` and the second object will be blessed as a `RuleObjectString`.

Answer (score 4):

This is 2012, so you should consider using proper OOP solutions instead of reinventing the wheel all over again.

By using [Moose](https://metacpan.org/release/Moose), the solution would look something like this (untested):

RuleObject.pm

```perl
package RuleObject;
use Moose;

has 'value' => ( isa => 'Str', is => 'rw', required => 0, default => '' );

1;
```

RuleObjectString.pm

```perl
package RuleObjectString;
use Moose;

extends 'RuleObject';

sub compare {
    my $self      = shift;
    my $compareto = shift;

    return $self->value =~ /$compareto/;
}

1;
```

Simple! :)

Comment: And for people who think `Moose` is too heavy, `Moo` is a very good lightweight alternative.

Comment: Isn't it good to understand how the language works and not rely only on library solutions though? (It being 2014 and the world almost overrun with developers.)

Comment: OP wanted to solve a specific problem, not learn Perl. The libraries are there for a good reason. :)

Comment: Fair enough, but if a man wants to fish; you wouldn't point him to the nearest seafood spot.

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping the object and see what it is.

```
print Dumper( $s )
```

It's going to be a RuleObject.

You might need to define a new() in RuleObjectString
and have it call Super::new().

Comment: Not necessary; the bug is as commented earlier. Namely, the use of unqualified `bless()` to bless into the calling package, not the class name provided.